# Should I use Lore or Mythos

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a scientific paper (on an unrelated subject), and the need arose to refer to Robin Hood stories in film, literature and folk culture in general. I would like to use the expression "the Robin Hood mythos", but was advised to consider using "the Robin Hood lore" instead.

I've always thought that "lore" refers to common wisdom, things that are actually "known". It makes me slightly uncomfortable to use the word in relation to legends and (probably) fictional stories.

Is "lore" correct here, or should I stick to "mythos"? Or would yet a third alternative be even better?

Edit: As requested, here's a bit more context:

"As written, the case text is notably terse in describing the full complexities of Robin’s situation. However, the Robin Hood ***mythos*** has been thoroughly explored in literature and film, resulting in an extensive shared mental model. This mental model was used to construct an imaginary Robin Hood and Merry Men. These constructs were then interviewed in order to complement the information presented in the case. Although the answers supplied were naturally ultimately made up, it was fairly easy to remain faithful to both the ***mythos*** and the case text."

Comment: Maybe show us the sentence you're proposing?

Comment: Sometimes, *universe* or *realm* are used to describe such things.

Comment: What's the matter with the word _myth_? Why use a fancy and questionbegging word spelled like Greek but pronounced like English? _Myth_ is precisely what RH is; just like King Arthur and Beowulf. A good story, told many times in many ways with many meanings by many people for many centuries.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was under the impression that _myth_ refers to one single story or one specific personage, whereas _mythos_ would encompass all the stories and versions thereof dealing with that character. I may well be wrong on this, though.

Comment: If you're a literary critic, maybe; probly depends on what church you go to. But in terms of cognitive metaphor, a _myth_ is just a very very thoroughly articulated and associated narrative of some kind that functions as a cultural given. Like [the _Darmok_ episode of _Star Trek_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darmok), which uses the myth of Gilgamesh as a model.

Comment: +1 for the question - an "archetype" is a shared mental model composed of myth, legend, and lore or *folk*lore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Collins (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lore):

> ***lore***
>
> noun
>
> 1) collective knowledge or wisdom on a particular subject, esp of a traditional nature
>   2) knowledge or learning
>   3) (archaic) teaching, or something that is taught

Also, according to Collins (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mythos):

> ***mythos***
>
> noun
>
> 1) the complex of beliefs, values, attitudes, etc, characteristic of a specific group or society
>   2) another word for myth, mythology

And from Collins also (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/myth#myth_1)

> ***myth***
>
> noun
>
> 1)  a story about superhuman beings of an earlier age taken by preliterate society to be a true account, usually of how natural phenomena, social customs, etc, came into existence
>         2)  another word for mythology (sense 1), mythology (sense 3)
>    3)  a person or thing whose existence is fictional or unproven
>       (in modern literature) a theme or character type embodying an idea   ⇒ "Hemingway's myth of the male hero"
>       (philosophy) (esp in the writings of Plato) an allegory or parable

After reading the edited question: I think that the best fit in this case would be ***lore*** if you want to express the culture or collective knowledge about Robin Hood, while if you want to make reference to the tale or the character itself, ***mythos*** would make more sense

Comment: That's funny, Robin Hood stories don't particularly strike me as "knowledge or wisdom", whereas Robin Hood is clearly "a person whose existence is fictional or unproven". In my reading, those definitions would seem to point to mythos rather than lore... Can you expand on your reasoning?

Comment: @JoãoMendes: Yes, of course. I base my reasoning in the fact that such collective knowledge is not required to be about non-fictional things. For example, you can find many references to fairy lore

Comment: @JoãoMendes: as I see it, lore would reference better the culture or collective knowledge about the subject (such as films, literature, folk-lore...) while mythos would refer more to the tale or the character itself

Comment: The argument in this last comment was the final selling point for me. I'm going to go with lore.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to split the difference, you might try

> **legend** *n*
>   1. a. An unverified story handed down from earlier times, especially one popularly believed to be historical.
>   1. b. A body or collection of such stories
>   <sup><sub>Definition from [TFDO](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/legend)</sub></sup>

This lets you introduce the idea of the story being unreliable, but leaves intact the supposition that some of it might actually be true.

[Edited to add definition 1.b. to forestall OP's objection that a legend is confined to a single act.]

Comment: Objection removed. Makes sense. I shall ponder on it.

Answer (score 4):

For many writers, contextual aptness tends to supersede correctness. In the paragraph you present, [*mythos*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/mythos) strikes me as an odd choice, albeit not incorrect. I would agree that there are other alternatives, and [*lore*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/lore) is a worthy one. To show that it works for *Robin Hood* (which I've always considered a [*legend*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/legend), by the way), here's the famous verse from Edgar Allan Poe's [*The Raven*](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/178713):

> *Once upon a midnight dreary 
>
> While I pondered weak and weary 
>
> Over a quaint and curious volume of forgotten **lore**
>
> While I nodded nearly napping
>
> Suddenly there came a tapping
>
> As of someone gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door*

Answer (score 2):

You can also use *tradition*: *Robin Hood tradition*.

Mythos - "a myth or mythology". (Oxford Dictionaries Online)

> ...thrived in an ether of **celebrity mythos** for nearly half a
>   century. (the BNC)

Lore - "a body of traditions and knowledge on a subject or held by a particular group, typically passed from person to person by word of mouth." (Oxford Dictionaries Online)

> The gesture, according to Hollywood lore,... (the BNC)

Comment: I was aware of these definitions. They don't really shed light on the question... I do like the suggestion to use "tradition". I shall ponder on it.

Answer (score 1):

OP asks, "Is "lore" correct here, or should I stick to "mythos"? ***Or would yet a third alternative be even better?"***

My answer is that a third alternative does, in fact, exist: "**archetype**", "*a shared mental model*" which is an admixture of myth, [folk]lore, and legend.

Your paragraph could then read: "However, the Robin Hood *archetype, a constellation of myth, folklore and legend*, has been thoroughly explored in literature and film, resulting in an extensive shared mental model. This mental model was used to construct an imaginary Robin Hood and Merry Men. These constructs were then interviewed in order to complement the information presented in the case. Although the answers supplied were naturally ultimately made up, it was fairly easy to remain faithful to both the *archetype* and the case text."

From Dissertations & Theses—Gradworks

**Archetypal analysis of Robin Hood and Maid Marian**

by Azmi, Kimberly, M.A., CALIFORNIA STATE UNIVERSITY, DOMINGUEZ HILLS, 2009, 72 pages; 1481385

*Abstract*: Robin Hood's story began in the Middle Ages as nothing more than a series of adventure tales. However, a transformation of the Robin Hood tradition occurred with works written between 1598 and 1911, and it can be demonstrated that through these works the stories about Robin Hood made a transition from simple archetypal narratives of adventure to more complex archetypal renderings, moving from Joseph Campbell's idea of the monomythic hero as one who does physical deeds to one who does spiritual deeds. Furthermore, the continuing popularity of these stories, over more than six centuries and in all formats, can at least partially be attributed to this archetypal transformation. Anthony Munday's two Renaissance dramas (1598, 1601) began this transformation, which was then further developed in works by Peacock (1818), Tennyson (1892), and Noyes (1911), the latter fully developing the spiritual aspects of this mythic tale. See, Dissertations & Theses—Gradworks [LINK](http://gradworks.umi.com/14/81/1481385.html)

**From, Robin Hood: A Mythic Biography by Stephen Knight**

Robin Hood is a constant presence in our history and literature, even as we change his name and appearance. Archetypal in form, he can represent Nature, a Folk-Hero, and a Trickster (although these elements of his character often intertwine and coalesce into what could be named the Robin Hood archetypal figure); see, About Education [LINK](http://classiclit.about.com/cs/productreviews/gr/aapr_robinhood.htm)

Comment: Sorry, if not clear. OP asks, "Is "lore" correct here, or should I stick to "mythos"? Or would yet a third alternative be even better?" My answer is, a third alternative exists which includes myth, [folk]lore, and legend--ARCHETYPE. "However, the Robin Hood archetype, a constellation of myth, folklore and legend, has been thoroughly explored in literature and film, resulting in an extensive shared mental model." (this shared mental model you refer to is precisely the definition of an archetype). "Although ... it was fairly easy to remain faithful to both the [archetype] and the case text."

Comment: +1. I appreciate the suggestion. It's not appropriate for this particular audience, but it did increase my understanding of the term.